# ORDER BY cannot reference outer query column?

Tags: sqlite

The SQL in question is this,

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable ( 
    myTableId INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE otherTable ( 
    otherTableId INT NOT NULL
);

SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            otherTable
        ORDER BY
            myTable.myTableId / otherTable.otherTableId ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
FROM
    myTable;
```

[SQLite 3.30 DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fhYE6CD9Esvhgp2S6xF9EY/0)

When executing the above with SQLite, I get,

> Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: myTable.myTableId

However, it works fine with [MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6TPVxMebHpUdDsVzN5Py6z/0), [PostgreSQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9M16ckRup3yhx4Vn1kK3R7/0), and [MS SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3cef/3)

---

The query is contrived and doesn't make much sense.

However, I don't see a good reason to not allow outer query references inside the `ORDER BY` clause.

Does anyone know **why** this is forbidden by SQLite?

I couldn't find anything in https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html about it.

Comment: SQLite is a simple file-based embedded database. It doesn't support many SQL features. In this case though, this `ORDER BY` expression is really weird. What is this trying to do? Return any random row from the inner table whose ID is less than the outer one? That's what `WHERE` is for: `WHERE myTable.myTableId / otherTable.otherTableId` followed by an `ORDER BY` clause determining which rows to retrieve, rather than a random one.

Comment: I wasn't trying anything concrete, in particular. It's easy to refactor this to not use `myTable.myTableId`. I was just messing around with possible edge cases across databases and discovered this.

Comment: The interesting question is "What does that execution plan look like"? This query may be allowed, but it would have to scan the *entire* table to calculate the `ORDER BY` value. That's very expensive, especially in big tables. Maybe some query optimizer would convert this to a `WHERE` and stop when the first match was found. It still wouldn't be able to use any indexes

Comment: Admittedly, I've never had to order by an expression using an outer query column. Just to be sure, I went back on some previous projects and checked, and came up empty. But just because I've never done it, and I can't think of a valid use case for it,  and the particular sample query I posted is inefficient, doesn't mean it should be forbidden! But since it **is** forbidden, I got curious about the "why". Maybe they felt implementing it wasn't worth the maintenance cost, maybe they forgot, maybe the architecture makes it infeasible. I have no clue.

Comment: You can use `myTable.myTableId` in a `WHERE` in the correlated subquery just fine... No idea why it wouldn't be accepted in the `ORDER BY`. Maybe a bug? Bring it up on the sqlite mailing list, see what the developers say?

Comment: @JustinAnyhowStep "_ But since it is forbidden_" to be a bit picky... it may not be that it's explicitly _forbidden_ (as in: there's a bit of code that checks for this and disallows it). It's (probably) more likely that it hasn't been _explicitly allowed_ (no one's _added_ code to permit it). Given you've never used such a construct, it's at least plausible that no one else using SQLite has tried to (or, at least, let the devs know that they tried to use it and failed). If you _do_ report it on the mailing list, it may help if you can find a plausibly-useful use-case.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try the mailing list and see what the response is!